# Issue with Re Running While If/Else statement again until it breaks in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginning self taught programmer learning python for my first language.

In my journey, ive so far learned up to the point of If/Else statements, while loops, and break/continue

Ive decided to make a command interface program on repl.it and ive created all the commands and their functions

So with the context out of the way, here is my issue

The commands are in an if/else statement which is in a while loop, works fine, but after one command is carried out the program ends. (thats why i put the if/else statement in a while statement)

So ive tried making a command to stop the program with a command that breaks the loop by changing a variable and added “continue” to the end of the if/else statement

It ran the command again instead of running the program as a whole again so i tried adding it to the end of the while statement but all i got was an error saying invalid indentation

heres what i wrote (minus the if statements because they arent the issue):

```
while run == "True":
   if/else statement
   continue
```

Comment: Use `while True:` to loop infinitely. Then use `break` in the `if` statement when you want to stop the loop.

Comment: If you want more specific help, post the actual code.

Comment: @Barmar thanks i was able to fix it with that method and added continue to each command statement in the if/else statement and added the break statement to the command that stops the program

Comment: You don't need continue unless you need to skip over the rest of the loop body. Loops continue automatically, that's why they're called "loops".